# Should I buy a CPU or a GPU for doing calculations?

Tags: high-performance-computing, graphical-processing-unit

A few years ago there was a significant difference between CPUs and GPUs for performing calculations. It was quite clear when to go for a CPU or a GPU.

Today there are GPUs with a very large number of cores and threads. I was away from the subject for a while.  Is there still such a marked difference?  Or can a CPU reasonably well replace a GPU in, say, molecular dynamics?

Where should one put the money?

Comment: You might need to give detail about what type of calculations are your bottleneck. If you are doing calculations where RAM is the bottleneck, you do not want to use GPUs (except *maybe* if you're using IBM CPUs with NVIDIAs NVLink). If you are doing deep learning, then GPUs are what you need. It all depends on what you're doing!

Comment: It all depends on how the parallelization on your code is implemented. 

I had the experience of doing a molecular dynamics in 24 cores during 2 months. The same calculation took less than 24h in my notebook GPU (GTX1050Ti).

Comment: @I.Camps That makes clear that the situation is still the same despite CPU with dozens of cores

Comment: @user1420303 - I think everyone is asking you to be a bit more specific. Are you running molecular dynamics with a GPU-accelerated code? How big is the simulation system, etc.?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison, I do not have a problem in mind. I had work in ab-initio, MD, DFT, Monte Carlo, and some other simulation techniques. I just tried to ask if they perform similarly. It seems like is not the case. Also, I think I made some mistake when Sign-Up to this Community from my cell-phone as I just realized that I have a duplicate user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As other answers have mentioned, it depends a lot on the workload and the availability of GPU-acceleration for the codes you use (or write). In principal, there are multiple platforms, but in practical use right now, Nvidia CUDA has the best performance and largest use.

Nvidia offers a [GPU Application directory](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/gpu-accelerated-applications/) - listing existing codes with CUDA availability.

- Many molecular dynamics codes are already GPU-enabled and show huge speedups over CPU versions (e.g., https://developer.nvidia.com/hpc-application-performance). This includes LAMMPS, AMBER, GROMACS, NAMD.. pretty much everything. Speedup varies, but I've often seen 20x-100x show up.
- Fewer quantum codes are GPU-enabled with mixed results, largely dependent on how much work has gone into writing GPU versions of the code. These include VASP, Quantum Espresso, CP2k, Abinit, BigDFT, Gaussian, GAMESS, etc. I've seen some good benchmarks for commercial GPU acceleration of [Q-Chem called BrianQC](https://www.brianqc.com) and [Terachem](http://www.petachem.com/performance.html) but these are not widely deployed. On codes like Quantum Espresso and VASP, even Nvidia is [quoting a 10-20x speedup](https://developer.nvidia.com/hpc-application-performance).

For machine learning, speedup can be much, much more dramatic if your workload can be stored on the GPU. Data Center GPUs can be 16GB to 32GB in the Tesla V100 cards, and now 40GB in the A100 cards, although there's some overhead (i.e. you don't get to use all of that for your data and model).

Answer (score 12):

It depends a lot on your application. All problems can be solved on a CPU, **some** problems can be solved much faster on a GPU.

One thing to consider is the effort required to write your code. If you're writing your own code from scratch, adapting it for the GPU can be a lot of work, and potentially for little to no reward. On the other hand, if you're using software packages or certain libraries, enabling GPU support might be as simple as checking a box.

Are you talking about configuring your own personal/work computer? How much do you plan on running your code on your machine itself (rather than a cluster, or dedicated workstation). If you're going to be running your code on a cluster, the amount of simulation you can get done on your personal machine won't matter much. In that case, you might want just enough CPU and GPU to do development and short tests.

Answer (score 11):

Generally, CPUs give you the best bang for buck. While GPUs are promising, support for them is lacking in many codes. Moreover, even if some codes do support GPUs, the speedups are embarassingly small. Good GPUs are quite expensive: e.g. NVidia cards cost several thousands of dollars, and to get the best efficiency one might need several of them. For this price you can just get more CPUs.

So, short answer: check first if the program you want to run supports GPUs, and what is the speedup for a representative calculation. (Note that the published numbers may not match your use case!) Then, do the math: is spending money on a GPU worth it?

Comment: I think this depends a lot on the type of calculation. MD has shown amazing GPU acceleration and I think all the major codes support CUDA. That's less true with quantum codes of all types.

Comment: Yes, which is why the guideline is: check for speedup, calculate the price :)

Answer (score 2):

So long as your calculations are parallelizable, using GPU's should provide significant speedup over just using CPU's alone. Nvidia last week at their GTC conference announced their new A100 GPU, which provides up to 20X speedup over its predecessor, the Volta V100. [Nvidia debuts the A100, its most powerful graphics processor yet](https://siliconangle.com/2020/05/14/nvidia-debuts-a100-powerful-graphics-processor-yet/). Each A100 can deliver up to 600 Teraflops of performance.

A new DGX server with 8 A100's, while delivering 5PetaFlops performance (which is equivalent to the performance of the world's largest supercomputer a few years ago), will set you back around $200k. While this can be out of the price range of a lot of (but not all) academic labs, a cost-effective option could be a pay-as-you-go machine instance on AWS, or another cloud provider such as GCP or Azure. An example of a relevant deep learning AMI can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07Y43P7X5).

Comment: We're able to do some things on GPU, but the other catch is memory. Even on the DGX A100, you've got 40GB per card, vs. 1TB system memory. I'd guess that some types of quantum chemical integrals just won't fit on the GPU - much like the disk v. RAM questions with CPU.

Comment: I think GPUs are great, but benchmarking and tuning is almost always needed.